# QTextDocument in QAbstractItemDelegate paint method

Tags: qt, qt5.4, qtextdocument

I have a class which inherits `QAbstractItemDelegate` and I use `QTextDocument` inside the `paint()` method. My model contains two items, but when I run my qt application, the items are drawn in the first item of `QListView`.
**CODE**

```
void ProductItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    bool selected = (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) == QStyle::State_Selected;

    if (selected)
    {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());
    }

    painter->save();
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    if (selected)
    {
        painter->setPen(option.palette.highlightedText().color());
    }
    else
    {
        painter->setPen(option.palette.text().color());
    }

    mTextDocument.drawContents(painter);

    painter->restore();
}

QSize ProductItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    MyItem *myItem = index.data(Qt::UserRole + 1).value<MyItem *>();

    mTextDocument->clear();
    mTextDocument->setDefaultFont(option.font);
    mTextDocument->setPageSize(QSizeF(option.rect.width(), -1));

    QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(mTextDocument);

    QVector<QTextLength> columnConstraints;
    columnConstraints << QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 60);
    columnConstraints << QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 30);
    columnConstraints << QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 10);

    QTextTableFormat tableFormat;
    tableFormat.setBorder(1);
    tableFormat.setBorderBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
    tableFormat.setColumnWidthConstraints(columnConstraints);

    QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(2, 3, tableFormat);
    table->mergeCells(0, 0, 1, 3);

    QTextCursor cellCursor;

    QTextTableCell cell00 = table->cellAt(0, 0);
    cellCursor = cell00.firstCursorPosition();
    cellCursor.insertText(myItem->name());

    QTextTableCell cell10 = table->cellAt(1, 0);
    cellCursor = cell10.firstCursorPosition();
    cellCursor.insertText(myItem->text1());

    QTextTableCell cell11 = table->cellAt(1, 1);
    cellCursor = cell11.firstCursorPosition();
    cellCursor.insertText(myItem->text2());

    return mTextDocument->size().toSize();
}
```

**These are the result of the code above.**

The item was not drawn in second entry.
[image: Capture 1]

Both items are painted in the first entry.
[image: Capture 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your painter to the right spot before painting with it.

After the first `painter->save()` add :

```
painter->resetTransform();
painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Can you explain your answer more? I looked into Qt docs about `QAbstractItemDelegate` and I have never seen these two lines of code.

Comment: As I understand it, the initial position of the QPainter is at the topLeft() of the parent. (a TreeView I imagine?)